# What's the difference between "of" and "out of"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between the two?

> 1. She crafted the bookcase ***out of*** solid pine wood and then painted it.
> 2. She crafted the bookcase ***of*** solid pine wood and then painted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use ***of*** when it is **obvious** what substance has been used to make something:

> This little doll is **made of wood**.

We use ***out of*** when we **emphasize** the substance from which something is made:

> This little doll is **made out of** wood, not plastic.

So, both of your sentences are correct. But the accent is on different things:

> She crafted the bookcase **out of** solid pine wood and then painted it. *(it was solid pine! whether you are "excited" about the use of pine wood or the fact that it's solid depends on the context)*
>
> She crafted the bookcase **of** solid pine wood and then painted it. *(it's just a fact, solid pine wood is a basic material used)*

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable, as would be

> 3. She crafted the bookcase from solid pine wood and then painted it.

A minor difference in connotation is that `from` and `out of` draw attention to the material used, `solid pine`, whereas just `of` places a bit less emophasis on material.